# Generalized variance

Tags: matrices, correlation, determinant

Generalized variance is the determinant of correlation matrix. Does increasing the off-diagonal entries (correlation coefficients) decreases the determinant? Is a proof available?
All elements are positive. Can we deduce from Hadamard inequality of determinant?

Comment: The determinant of the _covariance_ matrix could be considered a generalization of variance, in that it's equal to the scalar variance in the case of dimension 1.  But the determinant of the correlation matrix, as opposed to the covariance matrix, is not in that sense a generalization of the variance.

Comment: May I ask for references to the definition of generalized variance you have mentioned? On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) it says that the variance is generalized as the trace of the matrix.

Answer (score 5):

It can do either. $\;$ Suppose the correlation matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x \\ x & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

$\operatorname{det}\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x \\ x & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right) = 1\cdot 1-x\cdot x = 1-x^2$

If $x<0$ then increasing the off-diagonal entries increases the determinant.

If $0<x$ then increasing the off-diagonal entires decreases the determinant.

Comment: Thanks... Does it generalizes for $N$. Let us supposes all elements of the correlation matrix are positive.