# How is generalized sample variance defined?

Tags: statistics, variance, covariance

I'm well aware on [this question on Generalized Variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60072/generalized-variance) that says that

> Generalized variance is the determinant of covariance matrix.

So it would be:

$$\operatorname{var}_G(\matrix{A}) = \operatorname{det}\operatorname{Cov}(\matrix{A})$$

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#For_vector-valued_random_variables) however, it says:

> Another natural generalization of variance for such vector-valued
>   random variables $\matrix{X}$, which results in a scalar value
>   rather than in a matrix, is obtained by interpreting the deviation
>   between the random variable and its mean as the Euclidean distance.
>   This results in $\operatorname{E} \left[(X-\mu)^{\operatorname{T}}(X-\mu )\right]=\operatorname{tr}(C)$, which is the trace of
>   the covariance matrix.

So it would be the sum of the variances of the single vectors in the covariance matrix:

$$\operatorname{var}_G(\matrix{A}) = \operatorname{tr}\operatorname{Cov}(\matrix{A})$$

I'm failing to find a publication defining it on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=generalized+sample+variance&btnG=), so I'm asking here **how is the generalized sample variance defined?**

Thanks!

Comment: Here is the oldest reference I could find: https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/24/3-4/471/378918?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: It defines a version for the Gaussian and other distributions, but no specific mentions for the sample variance is given (I believe). Maybe I just did not see the definition, is there one?

Thank you very much though.

Comment: Look at page 476: "We shall adopt as the generalized sample variance the determinant $|a_{ij}|$."

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks! But then from where does the one based on the trace presented on wikipedia comes from?

Comment: It is another measure of dispersion - the expected squared distance from the mean.

Comment: That for sure, do you have any references for also that formula? So that a proper answer addressing both definition could be formulated for others.

Comment: It seems that the trace of a cov. matrix is not widely used for that purpose (measure of dispersion). The only application I've found so far is PCA.